# Command failed to process: Causes: - request failed - Empty response Error occurred

Tags: php, laravel, imap

How to move email from one folder to another, I'm using Laravel 10.
laravel-imap library.
Below is the code and error displayed.

Img with my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gofi6.png)
error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrAP4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2gbX.png)

Comment: Please provide your code inline, copy pasted.  Do not use images.

Comment: Did you get any solutions ? Please post answer if you get this.